# A way to capture Http Response of the latest page from redirects/relocations

Tags: c#, .net, response, dotnet-httpclient

Is there a way to capture the last landing page's HTTP response/HTML in .NET?

This is what happens:

1. Use `HttpClient` to POST [www.website.com/login](http://www.website.com/login)
2. /login responds with a new location
3. App JavaScript handles the new location by using `window.location = www.website.com/newLocation`
4. I want to capture the response where it was redirected to

When I use HttpClient, it is only able to capture the new location in Step 2 and it will not capture anything further after that.

Is there a way to capture HTTP response in Step 4? I'm specifically after the HTML code that is passed back to the browser.

Comment: _"App JavaScript handles the new location by using window.location = www.website.com/newLocation"_ - `HttpClient` doesn't handle Javascript as it's not a web browser. You'll want browser automation such as Selenium or Puppeteer.

Comment: A HttpClient does every thing a webpage does except it doesn't put the response into a View.  So using a HttpClient is faster and uses less memory than the browser.  The one difference between a webpage and a HttpClient is the default HTTP Headers.  A webpage will do a lot of things automatically that a HttpClient will not do.  You have to add more code to get the HttpClient to work. If you are using HTTP (not secure) you can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare a working browser connection with the HttpClient to see differences.  Then make the HttpClient look like the browser.